# App version not showing in playstore, as a result a flutter package named upgrader is not working as expected

Tags: android, flutter, exception, google-play, app-store

I have published a flutter app to playstore. App is currently in **open testing track**. But the app version is not showing in playstore so that a package named upgrader is not working as expected.

Package log shows the following error line
upgrader: PlayStoreResults.redesignedVersion exception: FormatException: Not a properly formatted version string

I have tried editing store settings in play console. But the version is not showing in the playstore

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mention the app versions in your pubspec.yaml file before building the appbundle or apk?

You should mention the version like 0.0.1+1, if it is the first ever version and increase this version as you build new updates of your app.

Learn more about versioning a flutter app here - [Flutter App - Pubspec.yaml](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec#version)

Comment: Yes. I have mentioned the version.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. It appears that the version is missing for our app, which is currently in open testing. I attempted to use various packages, but they all had the same implementation of parsing the response from the following URL: "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.android&hl=en&gl=US". Unfortunately, this URL did not provide the version information as it does for other published apps.

So, I've switched to use [in_app_update](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_update) package which specifically provides the version code and upgrader only for iOS.

Comment: upgrader package is working in iOS. It is not working in android.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue, i figured out a way to fix such error. let me brake it down for you, what i did was quite simple.

```
UpgradeAlert(
      upgrader: Upgrader(
        showLater: true,
        showIgnore: false,
        countryCode: "NG", // Add this, but replace "NG" with your country code
        canDismissDialog: false,
        debugLogging: true,
        shouldPopScope: () => false,
        dialogStyle: Platform.isIOS
            ? UpgradeDialogStyle.cupertino
            : UpgradeDialogStyle.material,
      ),
    )
```

From the above code you should notice the params that look quite different was the `countryCode: "NG"`. Which was added because i am from Nigeria and my app was publish in Nigeria, so replace such with your own country code and it should work as expected.

EXP: if you are from "United Kingdom" you should add "UK".